# Why does this expression work in one spot but not another when using the same data?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have 2 reports here that are machine schedules (**Wrap** & **Moulder**). They were working great, until I tried to add a checkbox to say whether or not the previous step had been marked completed. It worked initially on Wrap Schedule but when I did the exact same thing on Moulder Schedule it is coming out as data type mismatches. In the checkbox I have put the expression:

```
=IsDate([Previous_Date_Ran])
```

It works great on Wrap Schedule, but as soon as a Date is entered in the [Previous_Date_Ran] field I am getting data type mismatches. I have narrowed it down to whenever a date is put into that field, which is odd because when it is Null there is no issue. I have made sure already that my other form that supplies this [Previous_Date_Ran] field is inserting =Date() and not =Now() or =Time(). Below will be screenshots of it working on Wrap but erroring on Moulder.

[image: Checkbox Expression Wrap Schedule]

[image: Checkbox Expression Moulder Schedule]

[[image: Wrap Schedule Working redacted3]

[image: Moulder Schedule Error]

[image: Moulder Schedule no error redacted]
Thank you if you have suffered through with me so far, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `IsDate` can only return _True_ or _False_, so something else is going on.

Comment: @Gustav I promise it is something very weird and not another control, I have taken every control off of the report except that check box, and when there is no date entered in the field [Previous_Date_Ran] it opens without a data type mismatch. I thought maybe it had to do something with how Access evaluates check boxes, -1 being True and 0 being False, but it shouldn't work on the Wrap Schedule then. I can make an edit and show that screenshot as well if you'd like verification to be sure.

Comment: Then I would rebuild the report.

Comment: Now() and Time() data would evaluate to True. Gustav could be right to suggest rebuilding - sometimes weirdness is corruption that cannot be explained. You want checkbox to show False if field is Null otherwise True? Alternative expression: `=Not IsNull([Previous_Date_Ran])`. Try doing the calc in query and binding checkbox to field.

Comment: @June7 I have tried as well to use DateValue incase the fact that Date() still has the time of Midnight tied to it could be causing the issue and I still data type mismatch. Compact and repair has no effect either, so I guess I am down to rebuilding the Query as well as the Report since both of them error.

I will post how that goes Monday, with any luck it's just Access being weird and a rebuild as @_Gustav  suggested works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone still struggling here is the steps I took to fix this problem:

Firstly, I have the field Date_Ran as a Date/Time, formatted to short date. Another form has an on-dbl-click event where it inserts today's date in the field. Turns out when you use =Date() in VBA is assigns it a default Variant type. For whatever reason I believe this was what caused the error. The second I switched to using =Date$() it inserts today's date as a string and the error has stopped. Good luck!